# Minimum step size for x axis in Octave plot?

Tags: octave, matlab-figure, axis

## Context

Using Octave 7.1.0 (same result with 8.2.0), I wanted to plot on a density map using `pcolor()` and a bar graph using `bar()` functions. I then wanted the axis to range from precomputed values in my code. When the figure first showed up, both plot had the right axis. **However, when I enlarged or rescaled the whole figure, the original axis zoom was lost**. I was able to pin point the problem to the step size of my x vector.

## The Problem

You can experience the same behavior by running this code and commenting/uncommenting the definition of the `t` vector.

```
clc
clear all
close all

n = 200;
bins = peaks(n);
t = [0:1e-11:(n-1)*1e-11];  % This vector creates the bug
%t = [0:1e-10:(n-1)*1e-10];  % This vector works
timeAxis = [t(50) t(end-50)];

figure
plot(t, bins(:,50))
axis manual
xlim(timeAxis)
hold off
```

Here is a picture of the plot before and after the user put the figure in full screen. Octave does not throw any warnings/errors.
[image]

While using `t = [0:1e-11:(n-1)*1e-11]`, how can I ensure the axis zoom stays the same after the user full screens the figure?

Comment: The last value in `centers` is equal to the last `edges` value... Is it correct? Maybe `centers = edges(1:end-1) + 0.005` ?

Comment: @Joao_PS, thank you for your comment. The `centers` vector is correctly assigned in the code as of now. My problem is about the axis of the graph changing when I don't want to.

Comment: @Joao_PS, I did some further debugging and found the source of the problem to be the x axis vector. I edited the question so it is easier to replicate on your side. Thanks,

Comment: This is really weird! Unfortunately I haven't found a solution.

Comment: You may want to put that image here in the question now that you have enough rep.

Comment: This seems like a bug. Why not create an issue in the issue tracker for the Octave project?

Comment: @CrisLuengo you are right. Here is the bug report: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?64221

Answer (score 1):

So I found a work around to this problem by simply multiplying the x vector (`t`) by the closest power of 1000 (1e3, 1e6, 1e9, etc.) that is smaller than the original step size.

```
clc
clear all
close all

n = 200;
bins = peaks(n);

% From the original step size, find the closest 1e3 factor
tstep = 1e-11;
factor = floor(abs(log10(tstep)/3));
factor = 10^(3*factor);

t = [0:tstep:(n-1)*tstep];
timeAxis = [t(50) t(end-50)];

figure
% Original
subplot(1,2,1)
hold on
title('Original Bug')
plot(t, bins(:,50))
xlim(timeAxis)
xlabel('Time (s)')
hold off
% Work around with factor multiplication
subplot(1,2,2)
hold on
title('Work around')
plot(t.*factor, bins(:,50))
xlim(timeAxis.*factor)
xlabel(['Time (1e-', num2str(log10(factor)), ' s)'])
hold off
```

Comment: Very good! I even tried using factor = 10, but it didn't work... so I didn't try with larger values...

Comment: @Joao_PS this is weird because when I hardcode `factor = 10` at line 12, it works on my end.